# How to get browser breakdown for advanced segments in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

When I look at the 'Browser & OS' report in Google Analytics I see the following chart:

[image: analytics chart without segment applied]

However, when I apply an advanced segment to the report I get the following chart:

[image: analytics chart with segment applied]

I'm guessing that the grey area of this second chart represents all the traffic outside of my segment, and that the other ~29% that is colored is my segment's browser breakdown.  I can certainly do the math to figure out the percentage breakdowns inside of my advanced segment manually, however if I were to email this report to a client I think they'd be confused.

Is there a way to get the chart for the advanced segment to exclude the traffic outside of the segment completely?  Ideally the chart for my advanced segment would look the same as the first chart I posted, and only represent the traffic within that segment.

Answer (score 1):

I found your post as I was searching for the same answer.

I think I've figured it out, using custom reporting.

1. Go to Google analytics ***Custom reporting*** (rather than Standard reporting)
2. Create a new report, with title and tab name.
3. Add metric groups (might as well add both ***visits*** and ***unique visitors***)
4. Add Dimension Drill downs (I chose ***Browser***, and then secondary: ***Browser version***)
5. Now in the filters area, apply the ***Advanced segment*** details
6. Hit ***Save***, then switch the explorer view to pie chart.

Hope that helps. It did for me.

But I agree with you, I think it should show the 100% of the segment you're on. Or at least give an option to switch to that view.